# transferhandler ignores drag event

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I set a transfer handler on a JTable (embedded in JPanel + JScrollPane).
Dragging elements from the table somewhere else (create transferable ...) works.
Drop elements to the table doesn't work,any drag event is ignored.
The problem might be an event consumer (consuming the drag event), but that's the only idea I have.

```
final JTable tbl = new MyJTable();
tbl.setDragEnabled(true);
tbl.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {


@Override
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
    // .... works
}

@Override
public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
    // ... never called

}

@Override
public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
  // ... never called
}
```

Comment: should work, probably something wrong with the code you are not showing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem working with a JTree and the solution was implementing `getSourceActions` in my `TransferHandler` and define the transfer action inside it. For example:

```
    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent comp) {
        return MOVE;
    }
```

Comment: no, dropMode only is used for deciding about the visual feedback of the drop location, not the drag/drop functionality itself

Comment: you're right, I'm deleting this awful answer. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I remember I had a similar problem but the previous answer was not the solution, thanks again for poiniting that out